# A question on static physics (equilibirium)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, equilibrium, statics

I have a question about static physics which includes multiple pullies and parts. I have tried to solve it but I have a problem which prevents me from solving the whole question. so I started from drawing a free-body diagram but I can't find the direction of the kinetic friction.
[image]

theta is 25 degrees.

so this is my free-body diagram:
[image]

at point A I'm enable to determine the direction of friction.
I also have to find a general term for the force from the wall in point A.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: If this is a statics equilibrium question, the friction would be static not kinetic. In any case, why do you think a friction force is even required for equilibrium?

Comment: Hi, the direction of friction will be defined once the system starts to move, and it will be opposite to the motion. If you want to find the equilibrium point of this system, you need to find where the sum of the forces vanish, where no motion is induced and thus there won't be any kinetic friction. (the story is different for static friction)

Comment: Also, your free body diagram for AO is missing a vertical reaction for the pin support at O.

Comment: @Seviserful The bar AO can't move down because it would have to shorten to do so. If it moves up, it will separate from the wall. In any case, I submit friction is not even needed at A for equilibrium. The vertical component of the tension BC plus the upward vertical reaction at the pin O (missing in the FBD) can counter the weight mg of bar. The horizontal reaction at O can counter the horizontal reaction a A.

Comment: @BobD Yes, you are right. In my comment I wanted to make explicit how to calculate the equilibrium point, noting that the kinetic friction is never necessary for that.

Comment: @BobD thanks a lot. I would be happy if you submit your comment as the answer of the question.

Comment: @infinite OK, will do.

Comment: @BobD I have another question. I would be happy if you could help. on pulley E there are two ropes can we write T=M1.g or should we say T=M1.g.0.5?

Comment: @infinite What does a free body diagram of pulley E tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bar AO can't move down because it would have to shorten to do so. If it moves up, it will separate from the wall. In any case, I submit friction is not even needed at A for equilibrium. The vertical component of the tension BC plus the upward vertical reaction at the pin O (missing in the FBD) can counter the weight mg of bar. The horizontal reaction at O can counter the horizontal reaction a A.

When you draw free body diagrams you should isolate (free) the objects of interest, in this case, the mass m1, pulley E and bar AO. See the diagram below.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all your free body diagram is a bit wrong just check your diagram that the mass M1 attached to the string will experience the force which will be equal to two times of tension in string not only T.

In other words the mass M1 will experience force equal to 2T.

And it won't experience kinetic friction because rod will just leave the contact with the surface after it will experience the torque provided by the tension in the string it will not slide over the surface friction only acts when the object is making a continuous contact with the surface that mathematically can be written as:-

```
F=μN
```

where N is the normal force exerted by the object so if there will be no contact with the surface then also there will be no normal force which is necessary for the friction force to come in action.

And the question you asked in comments that what is that E so that is nothing but its a name specifically given to that pulley for the sake of identification for example pulley A, pulley B etc. That's how its pulley E and it's a movable pulley that will move as the mass moves down its a completely different story because if the mass goes down by the displacement x then the string will be pulled down by 2x . Nothing else.

Thank you!
Hope it will help you a lot to understand!